# Enable ssh on a linux via filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a linux image (Ubuntu) on an SD card for an embedded device.
It boots and gets assigned an IP. However the ssh server seems to be disabled. 
I don't have a serial connection so I need to use ssh. For that ssh server needs to autostart.
How can I do that without having access to the bootet Ubuntu but via the mounted SD card on my host computer?

Comment: i don't knwo how you installed the ssh-daemon, but usually it creates the /etc/init.d/ssh when you install it with package manager or install script. And this should autostart it.

Comment: I did not install anything. I just copied the ubuntu image (http://boundarydevices.com/eula?file=linaro-raring-developer-20130926.tar.gz) to my SD card and booted the board. Now I need to figure out a way to get headless access. Port 22 does not respond.

Comment: Do you know if it has SSH installed? If it has, you can make your own init script.. like so  : http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html.. Assuming you can edit it with some card reader.

Comment: Are there any other open ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the card:

```
 sudo /dev/mmX1 /mnt
```

where mmX is whatever your system calls the card. Now:

```
 cd /mnt
 sudo chroot .
```

and this places into an environment where you only see the card, as if it were your root system. Now do

```
  sudo su
 echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
 echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
 apt-get install ssh
```

and you are done. Exit from chroot,

```
 exit
 cd
 sudo umount /mnt
```

and you are done.